# objective-c converting strings to usable numbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

I have strings that look about like this:

```
stringA = @"29.88";
stringB = @"2564";
stringC = @"12";
stringD = @"-2";
```

what is the best way to convert them so they can all be used in the same mathmatical formula?? that includes add, subtract.multiply,divide etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have NSString variables.

```
NSString *stringA = @"29.88";
NSString *stringB = @"2564";
NSString *stringC = @"12";
NSString *stringD = @"-2";
```

suppose, you want to convert a string value to float value, use following statement.

```
float x=[stringA floatValue];
```

suppose, you want to convert a string value to integer value, use following statement.

```
NSInteger y = [stringC intValue];
```

Hope, it helps to you.

Answer (score 2):

Probably `floatValue` (as it appears you want floating-point values), though `integerValue` may also be of use (both are instance methods of NSString).

Answer (score 2):

`[stringA doubleValue]`

Answer (score 1):

These are all wrong, because they don't handle errors well.  You really want an `NSNumberFormatter`.

If you have the string `@"abc"` and try to use `intValue` or `floatValue` on it, you'll get `0.0`, which is obviously incorrect.  If you parse it with an `NSNumberFormatter`, you'll get `nil`, which is very easy to distinguish from an `NSNumber` (which is what would be returned if it was able to parse a number).